# Symfony: Delete all the records in a table who have the id in the string in table's column

Tags: php, symfony

[Please note that I do not have code for this problem, I need code, I have tried to explain it the best way, and if you can help, it will be great]

so here is the deal, I have a field in the table named "order" for every user. The main job of the user is to bring other users to the system and when they bring a new user their id is sticked to (concated with) the referring user's id and stored in his "order field"

for eg.

user 'a' has id 31. 'a' brings in 'b' whose is assigned 32, now b's therefore b has the value: '31-32' stored in his 'order' field. simililarly if b brings in 'c' whose id is 35, the order for c will be: '31-32-35' and it goes so on.

Now when I delete 'a' I want ALL the users who have his id in their order fields, that is if i decide to delete 'a' in this above field, all the users should be deleted from he system too!

I want to do this via symfony controller, and I think that can be done by findAll() function in symfony but I have no clue how to use it.

Please help, I am really stuck!

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You have a parent-child relationship. The table should have a parent column. Then make that a foreign key and cascade on delete. Then, you delete one record and it cascades all children.

Comment: I have a parent column in the table, but the process becomes a recursive when you want to delete the child of a child, so we have to keep fetching ids and is logically more strainful

Comment: If you have a parent column AND you made it a foreign key AND you set delete on cascade THEN you only delete one record to delete all the children and children of those children and children of those children... It is far less "strainful" than trying to do it by hand. Further, it means that you won't accidentally forget to delete a child and have orphans running around.

Comment: How on earth can you add a foreign key between fields in the same table?

Comment: You use the exact same syntax as you do when it is a foreign key to another table. Instead of typing a foreign table's name, you type the table's name.

Comment: Actually it would be easier to store only direct parent's ID  as a association and tell doctrine to do cascade delete.

Answer (score 0):

I did by using a parent field in each table for the user:

and here is the code if such thing arises for someone:

```
<?php

$repo = $em->getRepository('SystemBundle:Distributor');
$temp = $slug;
$pd = $repo->findAll();
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($pd); $i++) {
    $u = $repo->findOneBy(['parent' => $temp]);
    if ($u) {
        $temp = $u->getId();
        $em->remove($u);
        $em->flush();
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
$dis = $repo->findOneBy(["id" => $slug]);
$em->remove($dis);
$em->flush();
```

Using for loop it was possible to do this